# prevent horizontal scrollbar from left and right div border

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and I am attempting to create this kind of layout

[image: screenshot]

I am able to do this using this

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="d3-d4 m1" id="logoHolder">
        <img src="images/payday_logo_long_web.png" alt="Pay Day IRA" />
    </div>
    <div class="d5-d10 m1" id="navHolder">
        <ul id="mainNavigation">
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Investment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--BREAK-->

    <div class="d1-d2 greenSideBar" id="leftGreenSideBar" >

    </div>
    <div class="d3-d6 m1" id="employerButton">
        Employer
    </div>
    <div class="d7-d10 m1" id="employeeButton">
        Employees
    </div>
    <div class="d11-d12 greenSideBar" id="rightGreenSideBar">

    </div>

    <!--BREAK-->


</body>
```

CSS

```
/*Green Side Bars*/
.greenSideBar{
    background-color:#6EBE44;
    height:35px;
}
    #rightGreenSideBar{
    border-left-width:5px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:white;
    }

/*Employee/Employer Buttons*/
#employerButton{
    background-color:#6EBE44;
    height:35px;
    border-left-width:5px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:white;
}


#employeeButton{
    background-color:#6EBE44;
    height:35px;
    border-left-width:5px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:white;
}
```

The only issue is that this is creating a horizontal scrollbar. Ive narrowed it down to be cause by the

```
border-left-width:5px;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-color:white;
```

of employeeButton, employerButton, and rightGreenSideBar

If I remove this, it has no horizontal scroll bar.

How can I achieve this look without the scroll bar.

I created a fiddle but it doesnt have the same issue.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5pKA/)

EDIT

Here is an example I uploaded to my server

[Example](http://voipstreet.com/testSite2/index.html)

Comment: so where is the scrollbar in your example?

Comment: example added. see above

Comment: On Chrome I see no scrollbar. Also, you do know that IRA has other meanings?

Comment: on which browser you see the scrollbar?

Comment: It depends on your screen resolution.. I guess that on small resolutions, a scrollbar appears. Just a thought

Comment: chrome, firefox, ie, and opera.

Answer (score 0):

You could always throw the elements with a border into a parent div so that the border and content all fit that box instead of allowing them to overflow. Hard to troubleshoot as is without the fiddle showing the bar

Answer (score 0):

add this to the wrapper element which has the scrollbar:

```
.wrapper { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Comment: This works but I feel isnt really the best solution. I dont know what is causing the scroll bar to be there in the first place. Does borders on div create padding?

Comment: No this is not an elegant solution, i agree. An elements real width is the sum of its width, padding and border.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped your bar area in a div (probably should have something to contain them all anyways), put a max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; and the bar is gone, with the functionality in place. Sure it may not be the perfect solution but you have stuff like margin-left: -100% going on. personally I would scrap the grid system you are using for that row and just specify the widths using percentages and use media queries to hide the outer blocks.